# Evaluate input to a VBA function before executing the function

Tags: vba, function, input, evaluate

I have created a VBA function to calculate a weighted average. The function has optional parameters ("criterias") that allow to restrict the weighted average calculation to a subset of rows only (all Apple rows in the example below).

The function works fine for inputs of the form :

`weightedAverage([5 2 5],[2 3 4], [Apple Orange Apple], Apple)`

If I change the input on the "criterias" as follows, the function returns an error:

`weightedAverage([5 2 5],[2 3 4], ([Apple Orange Apple]=Apple), TRUE)`

Is there a way that the function first evaluates the third input and translates it to `[TRUE FALSE TRUE]`?

(The workbook function sumproduct is able to handle inputs of the form `sumproduct(--([Apple Orange Apple]=Apple),...)`, which is why I am wondering whether is also possible for my function)

```
Function weightedAverage(vals As Range, weight As Range, ParamArray criterias() As Variant) As Double
' Calcualted Weighted Average of "vals" weighted by "weight"
' Optionally the weighted average can be constrained to certain "vals" only by using "criterias"


Dim totalweight As Double 'sum up weights where "vals" is a number and "criterias" is true
Dim result As Double 'sum up vals(i) * weights(i)
Dim takevalue As Boolean 'temporary variable store whether "vals" is a number and "criterias" are met


' Init
result = 0
totalweight = 0

' Loop over vals
For i = 1 To vals.Count

    ' Check whether vals is a numeric and not empty
    takevalue = IsNumeric(vals.Cells(i).Value) And Not (IsEmpty(vals.Cells(i).Value))
    
    ' Check whether criterias are satisfied
    For ii = 0 To UBound(criterias) - 1 Step 2
    
        ' Exit loop if condition is not satisfied
        If takevalue = False Then Exit For

        ' Test whether condition is true
        takevalue = ((LCase(criterias(ii).Cells(i).Value) = LCase(criterias(ii + 1).Cells(1).Value)) And takevalue)

    Next ii
    
    ' If all conditions are satisfied, add value to results and totalweight
    If takevalue Then
    
        result = result + vals(i) * weight(i)
        totalweight = totalweight + weight(i)
    
    End If

Next i

' Calculate weighted average
weightedAverage = result / totalweight

End Function
```

Comment: So you want us to re write your code?  What have you done to try and change the code to do what you want?

Comment: Are you using Ctrl+Shift+Enter to enter your example `weightedAverage([5 2 5],[2 3 4], ([Apple Orange Apple]=Apple), TRUE)`  I don't think it will work otherwise.  Your first example is simpler and doesn't require CSE

Comment: Thanks, @BigBen. I think that I am looping over the array in the inner loop (ii loop). But somehow the problems seems to be that my third input ([Apple Orange Apple]=Apple) first needs to be evaluated before being passed on the the VBA function. In Matlab I would use the eval function, but I could not find such a functionality in VBA

Comment: Thanks, Tim. I tried the Ctrl+Shift+Enter but it did not work. In addition, I googled whether there is a equivalent for eval (from Matlab) in VBA, but I could not find anything comparable. That's all a tried so far.

Comment: "my third input ([Apple Orange Apple]=Apple) first needs to be evaluated before being passed on the the VBA function" - which is why this can only work when using Ctrl+Shift+Enter, since that's how array formulas work on the worksheet. In my testing that led to an array of True/False getting passed in as the third parameter (so no need for that fourth TRUE parameter).

Comment: Thank you, Tim, very much appreciated. Your answer is spot on. If I drop the fourth input and use Ctrl+Shift+Enter, the function works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you, Tim, for your help. The function needs to be executed using Ctrl+Shift+Enter and the fourth input needs to be dropped.

The below weightedAverage function works with the following input:

`weightedAverage([5 2 5],[2 3 4], ([Apple Orange Apple]=Apple))`

```
Function weightedAverage(vals As Range, weight As Range, ParamArray criterias() As Variant) As Double
' Calcualted Weighted Average of "vals" weighted by "weight"
' Optionally the weighted average can be constrained to certain "vals" only by using "criterias"


Dim totalweight As Double 'sum up weights where "vals" is a number and "criterias" is true
Dim result As Double 'sum up vals(i) * weights(i)
Dim takevalue As Boolean 'temporary variable store whether "vals" is a number and "criterias" are met


' Init
result = 0
totalweight = 0

' Loop over vals
For i = 1 To vals.Count

    ' Check whether vals is a numeric and not empty
    takevalue = IsNumeric(vals.Cells(i).Value) And Not (IsEmpty(vals.Cells(i).Value))
    
    ' Check whether criterias are satisfied
    For ii = 0 To UBound(criterias)
    
        ' Exit loop if condition is not satisfied
        If takevalue = False Then Exit For

        ' Test whether condition is true
        takevalue = (criterias(ii)(i, 1) And takevalue)

    Next ii
    
    ' If all conditions are satisfied, add value to results and totalweight
    If takevalue Then
    
        result = result + vals(i) * weight(i)
        totalweight = totalweight + weight(i)
    
    End If

Next i

' Calculate weighted average
weightedAverage = result / totalweight

End Function
```